# Asp.net Bundle not render files .min

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, asp.net-optimization, webgrease

I've read and done the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290977/mvc-bundling-include-min-file-for-a-single-bundle), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971663/style-bundling-for-mvc4-not-using-min-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/mvc4-bundler-not-including-min-files) post!

Still can not use the Asp.net Bundles!

In `Global.asax.cs`

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles, Server);
```

and ...

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles, HttpServerUtility server)
{
    bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
    AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(bundles.IgnoreList);
    ...

    var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts")
        .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts", "*.js");
    bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
```

**Ignore list**

```
private static void AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(IgnoreList ignoreList)
{
    ignoreList.Ignore("*.intellisense.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
    ignoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
    ignoreList.Ignore("*.debug.js", OptimizationMode.Always);

    ignoreList.Ignore("underscore.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
    ignoreList.Ignore("moment.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
    ignoreList.Ignore("jquery-{version}.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
}
```

Still, files like `jquery.pnotify.min.js` are not rendered!

**Packages**

WebGrease                      1.3.0
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi... 1.1.0-Beta1

Comment: did you try this .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/jquery.pnotify.{version}.js");

Comment: I added this: `.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.pnotify.min.js")` and it worked!   

But I can not do this for all scritps with `.min` extension in this folder.
The idea IncludeDirectory is precisely this, **get all the script and create the bundle**.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I clear the IgnoreList and the min.js files are still ignored! This is driving me mad and I can't find a solution for this. Including each file specifically without any wildcards defeats the whole purpose of bundles. I result to directly include my scripts using normal <script> tags.

Answer (score 4):

OK! I figured it out! After looking around a bit in `BundleTable.Bundles` members found a `DirectoryFilter` apparently you have to `Clear()` that as well!

So `bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();` is not enough (it used to be) now you have to do `bundles.DirectoryFilter.Clear();` as well.

It worked for me, I hope that helps.

Comment: This is the answer I needed.  All others weren't working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess and say that you're running your application in `Debug` mode and not `Release` mode. In `Debug` mode `.min` files are ignored and it renders the un-minified script to help make debugging easier.

Comment: But I'm cleaning the Ignorelist.  

Still has this behavior? `bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the bundler will ignore files with a .min extension. Min files are preminified, and it is better if you let the optimizer minify the file itself.  You should put jquery.pnotify.js in the directory and then it will work just fine for you, delivering a non-minified, non-bundled version while debugging, and a minified and bundled version in release.

You can however, override the default (although I recommend you don't), by clearing the default IgnoreList and DirectoryFiler via `bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();` and `bundles.DirectoryFilter.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

In Application_Start:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```