# Bootstrap glyphicon content is broken after ASP.NET MVC minification

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bundling-and-minification

Minification in asp.net seems to break the bootstrap UTF symbols. I have this in the original file:

```
.glyphicon-edit:before {
  content: "\e065";
}
```

and this in the minified version:

```
.glyphicon-edit:before{content:""}
```

In theory I can add the pre-minified version instead, but that does not work for some reason either. I have asked this question earlier ([Asp.Net bundling not using the .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005594/asp-net-bundling-not-using-the-min-files)) but with no luck.

Any ideas how to fix the minification?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to the 1.1.3 of Optimization and in your bundleconfig, identify the css and include them using

```
     bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
.Include("style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```

and include the rest of the css files that you need which don't have a url reference or UTF char.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I fixed the issue somehow but not sure even how I did it since it's quite a long time ago :)